# Python kivy | Arabic text on Label text

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My problem when i try type arabic text 
My code is :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextInput(text='مرحبا بكم ')
myapp=TestApp()
myapp.run()
```

when i execute 
Textinput text is a some of Square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to give the label a font that support **Arabic**

```
#option1 -- on each TextInput
TextInput:
    font_name: "path/to/a/font/that/support/arabic.ttf"

#option2 override for all TextInputs
<TextInput>:
    font_name: ...
```

the warning from [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.font_name) says:

> Warning
>   Depending on your text provider, the font file may be ignored. However, you can mostly use this without problems.
>   If the font used lacks the glyphs for the particular language/symbols you are using, you will see ‘[]’ blank box characters instead of the actual glyphs. The solution is to use a font that has the glyphs you need to display. For example, to display unicodechar, use a font like freesans.ttf that has the glyph.

Comment: Any other way ?

Comment: why do you need another way? what is the problem? I guess you can override kivy's default font -- I've edited my answer about that

Comment: @Eng.Amaar Look at the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html) for `Config` and `Ctrl + F` for "default_font". ([GitHub repo file](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/5ec950838323a219136ff28ee63f643134502bd0/kivy/config.py#L207))